# Check if the sum of two different numbers in an array equal a variable number?

Tags: ruby, arrays, math, boolean

In Ruby, I would like to take an array of numbers, select 2 different numbers, add those 2 numbers together and see weather there equal to a variable x.y'd a variable x. Here is the code I used

```
def arrayIsEqual? (numArray, x)
  return true if numArray.sample + numArray.sample == x
  return false if numArray.empty? || numArray.count == 1
end
```

for example

```
numArray = [4,2,7,5]
x = 11
```

`arrayIsEqual (numArray, n)` should return `true`, since 4 + 7 = n(11)

How do I get this to work?

I don't want it to be 2 random numbers, just any 2 different numbers that add up to n

Comment: +1 for your attempt to show work in a beginner question, and your clearly articulated question.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: -1. Question is not clear. What do you mean by "select 2 different numbers and a variable x and see whether they are equal"? Which is equal to which?

Comment: Select 2 different numbers, and see if the sum of these 2 numbers is equal to a variable x

Comment: -1 and agree with sawa.. Context is not much clear..

Comment: Do you mean to check the sum for two numbers that are randomly picked (which seems to contradict your description), or all two numbers's sum must be x, or some two number's sum must be x?

Comment: I used the wrong method. I would like to check if the sum of any two numbers equals x. If equal, it will output true, otherwise it will output false

Comment: You have two votes to close so far, so you best edit your question, without delay (even though you've selected an answer)!  Do not attempt to explain what you mean in comments; do an edit.  For one, get rid of the reference to random values, as it just obscures.  Keep your example, it says (almost) all.

Comment: Cary. I believe he did well stating his question.  And the fact that one of the down votes is by someone who doesn't know proper English should be an indicator in the questioner's favor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to see if there are *any* two numbers in the array that add up to the specified value `x`. However, your code just picks two numbers at random and checks if those numbers add up.

Ruby has the [`Array#combination`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) method, which generates all combinations of a given length:

```
def contains_pair_for_sum?(arr, n)
  !!arr.uniq.combination(2).detect { |a, b| a + b == n }
end
```

A few things to note:

- First, we named it according to Ruby conventions: each word is `separated_by_underscores`. The `?` on the end means that the method is a predicate method and returns a true or false value.
- Inside the method, a few things happen. Let's look at that line, piece by piece.

  - `arr`: We take the array that was passed in.
  - `<...>.uniq`: We only look at the unique elements (because the OP wants to pick two different numbers).
  - `<...>.combination(2)`: We ask for all combinations from the array of length 2. If the array was `[4, 5, 6]`, we'd get `[[4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6]]`.
  - `<...>.detect { |a, b| a + b == n }`: We look for the first combination that adds up to `n`. If we found one, that's the result of that method. Otherwise, we get `nil`.
  - `!!<...>`: Finally, we take the result we got from `detect` and negate it twice. The first negation produces a Boolean value (`true` if the value we got was `nil`, or `false` if it's anything else); the second negation produces a Boolean value that's identical to the truth value of the first negation. This is a Ruby idiom to coerce a result into being either `true` or `false`.

Let's see it in action:

```
array = [4, 5, 9, 7, 8]

contains_pair_for_sum?(array, 11)
# => true (because [4, 7] sums to 11)

contains_pair_for_sum?(array, 17)
# => true (because [9, 8] sums to 17)

contains_pair_for_sum?(array, 100)
# => false (no pair matched)
```

Comment: The 2 numbers have to be different. And yes, I don't want to pick a random number. For example [4,4,7,8] the 4s can't be picked. This looks good, but I think instead of array, you should use arr, since that was defined first

Comment: If you could tell you don't want random numbers in post itself may be helpful for me.. :)

Comment: @user3545961: Do you want to see if there are *any two numbers* that sum to the value? Or do you just want to see *any two unique numbers*?

Comment: @user3545961: I updated. It'll only retrieve unique numbers now (that's what `#uniq` does).

Comment: Excellent response that breaks down the logic. Thank you

Comment: I tried writing a shorthand solution.  But mine ended up longer than yours.  Good job on your answer!

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't use any?

Comment: @seph I wanted to be able to demonstrate *which* pair was actually the correct answer too, which is in line with the semantics of `.detect {}`.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your question is "is there *any* pair of numbers in my array equals x", in which case this will do what you need:

```
def has_pair_equal?(num_array, x)
  (0..num_array.length-1).any? do |i| 
    num_array[i+1..-1].any? { |n| n + num_array[i] == x }
  end
end
```

This checks all sums of pairs of numbers in the array, and checks if their sum is `x`. `sample` *randomly* picks an item from the array, which means that what your code does is "return true *sometimes* if there is a pair of numbers in my array equals x"

Comment: I took the method name of yours.. don't mind please.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def array_is_equal? (num_array, x) 
  equality = 0
  num_array.each do |a|
    equality += 1 if a == x
    return true if equality == 2
  end
  return false
end
```

Use lowercase and underscores for variables in Ruby.  The convention is different here than in some other languages.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP meant - you count if there are two elements or more equal `x`, while the OP wants two elements whose _sum_ equal `x`. Btw, the code you wrote could be achieved by `num_array.count(x) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

One liner

```
x=[4,2,7,5]; x.each_with_index.any? {|y,i| x.each_with_index.any? {|z,j| unless i==j; z+y==11; end } }
```

And as a function

```
def pair_sum_match?(arr, x)
    arr.each_with_index.any? do |y,i|
        arr.each_with_index.any? do |z,j|
            unless i==j
                z+y==x
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Updated: Added each_with_index to avoid self inclusion on checks.  It's a lot longer now :-/

Comment: This will also return `true` for `[1,3,4] , 6` (it will check `3` against itself)

Comment: Now you have a problem if there are the same element twice (`[1, 2, 3, 2]`), and `delete_if` changes the array itself, so you are destroying the array as you go...

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out to me Uri.  I was hoping I could use less code to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over it once and use the target number to see if it matches. 100 times faster then most of the answers here

```
numbers = ( -10..10 ).to_a
numbers.unshift( numbers.first + -1 ) # if you do -20 or 20
numbers.push( numbers.last + 1 )
target    = 5
searched  = { }
matches   = { }
numbers.each do |number|
  if searched[ target - number + 1 ] == true
    matches[ "#{ number }_plus_#{ target - number }" ] = target
  end
  searched[ number + 1 ] = true
end
ap matches
```