# Ruby - Efficient method of checking if sum of two numbers in array equal a value

Tags: arrays, ruby, performance, loops

Here's my problem: I have a list of 28,123 numbers I need to iterate through and an array of 6965 other numbers checking if the sum of two numbers (can be the same number) have equal value to each of the 28,123 numbers. I want to put them in a new array or mark them as `true` / `false`. Any solutions I've come up with so far are extremely inefficient.

So a dumbed-down version of what I want is if I have the following: `array = [1, 2, 5]` and the numbers `1 to 5` would return `result = [2, 3, 4]` or the array of `result = [false, true, true, true, false]`

I read this SE question: [Check if the sum of two different numbers in an array equal a variable number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572515/check-if-the-sum-of-two-different-numbers-in-an-array-equal-a-variable-number) but I need something more efficient in my case it seems, or maybe a different approach to the problem. It also doesn't seem to work for two of the same number being added together.

Any help is much appreciated!

`non_abundant(n)` is a function that returns the first n non_abundant numbers. It executes almost instantaneously.

My Code:

```
def contains_pair?(array, n)
  !!array.combination(2).detect { |a, b| a + b == n }
end

result = []
array = non_abundant(6965)

(1..28123).each do |n|
  if array.index(n) == nil
    index = array.length - 1
  else
    index = array.index(n)
  end
  puts n
  if contains_pair?( array.take(index), n)
    result << n
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems like a job for a Set, because you can get much more efficient lookups than with an array.

Comment: I'm fairly new to ruby and haven't used sets yet. What method on sets am I looking for?

Comment: By _"two numbers"_ you mean the _sum_ of the two numbers, right?

Comment: Yes. Typo. Fixed now.

Comment: The title says _"two different numbers"_ which contradicts _"any two numbers (can be the same number)"_

Comment: Fixed. Not a good day for me I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = [1, 2, 5]
results = (1..10).to_a

numbers_set = numbers.each_with_object({}){ |i, h| h[i] = true }

results.select do |item|
  numbers.detect do |num|
    numbers_set[item - num]
  end
end
#=> [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10]
```

You can add some optimizations by sorting your numbers and checking if `num` is bigger then `item/2`.

The complexity is `O(n*m)` where `n` and `m` are lengths of two lists.

Another optimization is if numbers list length is less then results list (`n << m`) you can achieve `O(n*n)` complexity by calculating all possible sums in numbers list first.

Answer (score 0):

The most inefficient part of your algorithm is the fact that you are **re-calculating** many possible sums of combinations, **28123** times. You only need to do this **once**.

Here is a very simple improvement to your code:

```
array = non_abundant(6965)
combination_sums = array.combination(2).map {|comb| comb.inject(:+)}.uniq

result = (1..28123).select do |n|
  combination_sums.include? n
end
```

The rest of your algorithm seems to be an attempt to compensate for that original performance mistake of re-calculating the sums - which is no longer needed.

There are further optimisations you could potentially make, such as using a binary search. But I'm guessing this improvement will already be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: I'd change `uniq` to `to_set` (and `require 'set'` at the beginning). This can greatly improve performance.